# Convert the equation in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

How I can transform this equation into matrix form?

$$X_n=\alpha_1X_{n-1}+\alpha_2X_{n-2}+e_n$$

I know the final matrix form is $$\begin{pmatrix}
X_n\\ 
X_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1 &\alpha_2 \\ 
 1& 0
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
X_{n-1}\\ 
X_{n-2}
\end{pmatrix}+\begin{pmatrix}
e_n\\ 
0
\end{pmatrix}.$$

But how? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
X_{n} &=& \alpha_1 X_{n - 1} + \alpha_2 X_{n-2} + e_n \\
X_{n-1} &=& X_{n - 1}
\end{eqnarray}
$$

in matrix form

$$
\pmatrix{X_{n} \\ X_{n - 1}} = \pmatrix{ \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 \\ 1 & 0}\pmatrix{X_{n - 1} \\ X_{n - 2}} + \pmatrix{e_{n} \\ 0}
$$